# Bash script running program lines one after another

Tags: python, bash

This is my bash script. How to run the three command lines one after another (so the second command waits until the first finishes, and the third command waits until the second finishes).

```
#!/bin/bash

python /path/to/someprogramm.py analyze --probes /path/to/myfile.bed --rpkm_dir /path/to/RPKM/ --output /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --write_svals /path/to/SVD/singular_values.txt;

python /path/to/someprogramm.py call --input /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --output /path/to/calls.txt;

python /path/to/someprogramm.py plot --input /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --calls /path/to/calls.ng.txt --outputdir /path/to/call_images/;

echo "Command sequence finished succesfully"
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want them to start in parallel, and not wait for the previous one tro complerte before the next one starts?

Comment: I need to run one after another, since the second command takes as input the outut of the 1st command. So the second command should wait until the first finishes. and the third should wait the second.

Comment: Then just run the script, that is what will happen....

Comment: I get an error:  line 2: $'\r': command not found

Comment: You have a DOS (Windows) style line ending. Fix it on a GNU system with `sed -i 's/\r//' filename.sh`

Comment: @user3224522 : This is already the case, since you are starting the second command starts after the first one has finished.

Comment: @user3224522 An easier fix for the line endings problem is to use `dos2unix`. Even easier: Have your text editor generate the correct line endings when writing the file, so you don't have to think about this anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Bash is trying to eat some of your Python options. To fix that, wrap each line in quotes and put `eval` at the front:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval 'python /path/to/someprogramm.py analyze --probes /path/to/myfile.bed --rpkm_dir /path/to/RPKM/ --output /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --write_svals /path/to/SVD/singular_values.txt'
eval 'python /path/to/someprogramm.py call --input /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --output /path/to/calls.txt'
eval 'python /path/to/someprogramm.py plot --input /path/to/hdf5/analysis.hdf5 --calls /path/to/calls.ng.txt --outputdir /path/to/call_images/'
echo 'Command sequence finished succesfully'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It does by default. To *avoid* that, you can background each process by appending `&` to each line, but you didn't do that.
2. You don't need `;` at the end of a `bash` line.
3. You can ensure the next line follows a *successful* run by appending `&&` to each line and concatenating using a trailing `\`, or alternatively, `set -e` at the start of the script.

Comment: I tried && \, but unsuccessful, same error..  line 2: $'\r': command not found

Comment: as I commented above, that looks like embedded `\r` characters. you can fix it with `sed` as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, this should be happening anyway. If something is potentially going wrong, append `&&` to the end of each command rather than `;`. This prevents the other commands from starting if the previous command failed.

You may also want to add

```
set -e
```

to the beginning of the script (but after `#!/bin/bash`), to stop the whole script if a command fails.

And you can also add an `if` statement that checks the variable `$?`, this will have the value `0` if the previous command executed successfully.

One or more of these three options should enlighten you as to what is happening.

Comment: To be fair, I was drafting this at exactly the same time as that answer. Respectfully disagree that using `$?` is bad advice.. just a suggestion that would depend on how the script is ultimately written.

Comment: @Z4-tier, it often happens that someone else comes up with the same solution independently and doesn't see the other reply until posting his own. I've been on each end of it at times.

Comment: fair enough, I think I mistook `As mentioned already,` to refer to the other answer, but re-reading it now it probably is in reference to the comments on the question.

Comment: Yes, just a reference to the comments :)